# How to import image and video on the same plane and control their duration

Tags: image-sequence

I'm a complete beginner in blender ..i was wondering how to import an image and a video in one plane object and animate them..like playing still image for 100 frame and a video for another

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by 'same' plane, but I can tell you how to import an image or a sequence as a texture.

1. File -> Import -> Images as Planes and select your image (not sequence)

That creates a plane with the correct ratio x to y and applies your image texture onto it.

2. To change the texture into an image sequence, go the Shder Editor and click on the open folder icon of the texture node. Then locate your image sequence and select all images belonging to it (a).

Once you've done that the type of your texture changes to image sequence and Blender will detect how many frames there are. If you want to animate it, either animate the offset, or simply tick Auto Refresh, which will synch the sequence frame with the rendered frame.